# Why wget is getting just an empty folder?

Tags: wget

I am trying to mirror a site index similar to

> https://index.gd.workers.dev/

using wget. I run this code

```
wget -e robots=off --content-on-error --mirror -np -R "index.html*" https://index.gd.workers.dev/
```

It's giving this output:

> --2020-03-11 01:20:05--  http://index.gd.workers.dev/ Resolving index.gd.workers.dev (index.gd.workers.dev)... 104.31.87.133,
>   104.31.86.133, 2606:4700:3035::681f:5785, ... Connecting to index.gd.workers.dev (index.gd.workers.dev)|104.31.87.133|:80...
>   connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 361
>   [text/html] Saving to: ‘index.gd.workers.dev/index.html.tmp’
>
> index.gd.workers.de 100%[===================>]     361  --.-KB/s    in
>   0s
>
> Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off. 2020-03-11
>   01:20:05 (2.1 MB/s) - ‘index.gd.workers.dev/index.html.tmp’ saved
>   [361/361]
>
> Removing index.gd.workers.dev/index.html.tmp since it should be
>   rejected.
>
> FINISHED --2020-03-11 01:20:05-- Total wall clock time: 0.1s
>   Downloaded: 1 files, 361 in 0s (2.1 MB/s)

The end result is just a folder with the site name and nothing inside it. What am I doing wrong here? and is there any other way to mirror the directory?

Comment: I suggest you open up that page in a browser and then view source. It's just a script that outputs the page content, rather than the page content itself. Thet's probably the `tmp` file that gets created.

Comment: @paxdiablo so I have to start mirroring after the page content is output by the script? Any idea on how to do that or is there any delay command for wget?

Comment: Sorry, Jalaj, I can pontificate on what's *causing* your issue, but you'll have to wait for someone with more specific knowledge for a fix :-)